# Using sA+tB to derive equation of line.

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry

So I have two points (1,4,-1) and (2,2,7).

If I subtract the first from the latter, I get the vector $i - 2j + 8k$. Combined with the first point, I have the non-parametric equation: $ x-1 = - \frac{y-4}{2} = \frac{z+1}{8}$ as the equation of the line passing through these points.

So far so good.

I'm given that if A and B are position vectors for two points (such as the points above), then the vector that represents the line through these points is $sA + tB$ where $s+t=1$.

If I choose $s=0$, then $sA + tB = 2i + 2j + 7k$. This is neither the vector nor the line equation of the above.

How does this work? What am I missing?

Comment: You obtain the second point. What's so surprising?

Comment: What you are missing is that the equation must be (A- B)t+ B where A and B are the two "position vectors" or points.  With B= (1, 4, -1) and A= (2, 2, 7), A- B= (1, -2, 8) so the equation is (1, -2, 8)t+ (1, 4, -1). where t=0 gives B and t= 1 gives A.  You can also write it as At+ Bs where s= 1- t.  When t= 0, s= 1 so that gives B.  When t= 1, s= 0 so it gives A.  For 0< t< 1 it gives a point between A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do it.

$s(1, 4, -1) + t (2, 2, 7)$

This gives three equations.

$x = s + 2t$

$y = 4s + 2t$

$z = -s + 7t$

Let $s = 1-t$.

$x = 1+t$

$y = 4-2t$

$z = -1 +8t$

Solve for $t$ and we get $x-1 = -\frac{y-4}{2} = \frac{z+1}{8}$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Let two points be $ A (1,4,-1)$ and $B (2,2,7).$

$ s+t=1$.  It is straightforward. With $s=0$, then $ s A + (1-s) B $ is B.With $s=1$, then $ s A + (1-s) B $ is A.

Answer (score 0):

use $s+t=1$ to write the equation of the line ...

$$\ell(t) =(1-t)A+tB = A +(B-A)t$$